# How to get the last row per group of category?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, count, rank, partition

I want to label the last column with value 1 for the last record for each jobID, Product, Target. Please refer to table below.

| JobID | Product | Target | Expected Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC1 | 0 |  |
| 1 | ABC1 | 0 |  |
| 1 | ABC1 | 0 |  |
| 1 | ABC1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | ABC2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | ABC2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | ABC2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | ABC2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | ABC3 | 1 |  |
| 3 | ABC3 | 1 |  |
| 3 | ABC3 | 1 |  |
| 3 | ABC3 | 1 | 1 |

The target will always remain the same per jobid and product so it is basically repeating. I need to label the value 1 as shown in expected output for the last record per JobID, Product and Target. How can I achieve this in google sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the reverse search feature of `XMATCH`:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/LAMBDA(x, XMATCH(x, x,,-1)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)))(A2:A)*1)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), ">="&ROW(A2:A))=1, 1, )))
```

[image]

Comment: What is x in your formula?

Comment: @samronaldo309 `x` stands for "custom variable string" it can be anything you want like `candy` or `tornado` or `AbC` think of it as a placeholder for range - in this case A2:A

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATIVE:**

Here's a script version if you want to explore App Script.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //gets the active sheet
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 4); //gets A2:D13 dynamic to the number of rows
  var values = range.getValues(); //gets the value for the range

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
    
    if (values[i][0] == values[i + 1][0]) {
      console.log('TRUE');
    } else {
      values[i][3] = 1;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUERY` to `group by` Product and get the `max` row sequence corresponding to  that group. Then `MATCH` the row sequence against group max to get the expected result:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(rg,seq,IFNA(MATCH(seq,QUERY({rg,seq},"Select max(Col2) group by Col1"),0)))(B2:B13,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B13))))
```